Getting login validation "error" in login
I am working on the QR generator application for 2 step verification. While login credentials are correct in main.go and users.go still getting login validation failed. Here is the code:
Inmain.go
func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        _ = templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "login.html", nil)
        return
    }

    r.ParseForm()
    username := strings.TrimSpace(r.Form.Get("username"))
    password := strings.TrimSpace(r.Form.Get("password"))


    user, ok := users[username]
    if !ok || user.Password != password {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", http.StatusFound)
        return
    }

    if user.Secret == "" {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/generate-otp?username="+username, http.StatusFound)
        return
    }
    _ = templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "validate.html", struct{ Username string }{Username: username})
}

User.go
package users

// User represents a user with a username, password, and a TOTP secret.
type User struct {
    Username string
    Password string
    Secret   string
}

// In-memory "database" of users
var Users = map[string]*User{
    "john": {Username: "john", Password: "123" , Secret: ""},
}

I have checked with the username and password but it still shows authentication error.

Did you post full code ? It seems that you created map "Users" (capitalized) but you are trying to access that map with lowercase "users" in main.go. Maybe I'm missing something? Also, maybe don't use same name for struct and map (name it UserMap or something similar) to avoid confusion.
var UserMap = map[string]*User{
    "john": {Username: "john", Password: "123", Secret: ""},
}

user, ok := users.UserMap[username]

